# How do I apply a conditional statement to a 2D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a 2D array in python with numbers ranging from positive values to negative ones. However I need to set an 'if' statement that says something like: if an element of the 2D array is negative (less than zero) set the value to zero.

Here's a snippet of the code I've used:

```
final_array = np.random.randint(-1,1, size=(4,4))

for i in final_array:
    if final_array[i] < 0:
        final_array[i] == 0
```

When running this code I get the error: `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: It doesn't get the error you mentioned. your mentioned error may be duo to useing `==` instead of `=` for `final_array[i] == 0`. In this regard the best way will be indexing as the answer by *Lau*.

Comment: On top of the code not working (SyntaxError), fixing the obvious mistakes still gives a different error then the one you mentioned in the question ("ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()")

Comment: When you iterate on an array, or list, don't use that `i ` to index the array itself.  That doesn't make sense, even with python lists.  Do a simple iteration and look at the `i` values to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value of elements in a Numpy array using conditions. For example, the code below sets every element less than 0 equal to 0.

```
final_array[final_array<0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code I get a different error:

```
In [91]: final_array = np.random.randint(-1,1, size=(4,4))
    ...: 
    ...: for i in final_array:
    ...:     if final_array[i] < 0:
    ...:         final_array[i] == 0
    ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [91] in <cell line: 3>
    if final_array[i] < 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In [92]: final_array
Out[92]: 
array([[ 0,  0, -1,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0]])
In [93]: i
Out[93]: array([ 0,  0, -1,  0])
In [94]: final_array[i]
Out[94]: 
array([[ 0,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  0]])
```

Notice that `i` is a row of `final_array`.  While it works in this case, it doesn't make sense to use it as an index, does it?  It seems that you haven't read enough basic Python to do a simple iteration correctly.

For example with a list (of lists):

```
In [95]: alist = [[1],[3,4]]
    ...: for i in alist:
    ...:     print(i)
[1]
[3, 4]
```

`i` is one of the sublists, not an index!  Trying to use it as an index produces an error:

```
In [96]: alist = [[1],[3,4]]
    ...: for i in alist:
    ...:     print(alist[i])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [96] in <cell line: 2>
    print(alist[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Use `for i in range(len(arr)):` if you want to generate indices.  Or `for i,v in enumerate(arr):` to get indices and values.

But the error you got suggests that `final_array` was an array of floats, not integers that the code sample produces.

The `ambiguity error` that I got was the result of using

```
In [98]: Out[94]<0
Out[98]: 
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]])
```

the `if` statement.  `if` requires a simple True/False.  It doesn't do any sort of `iteration`.

Even proper indexing of a row of `final_array` would give this ambiguity error

```
In [100]: final_array[0]<0
Out[100]: array([False, False,  True, False])
```

The `if` only works if you are testing scalar elements of the array.  For example if the array was 1d:

```
In [101]: x = np.arange(-3,4)
In [102]: for i in range(len(x)):
     ...:     if x[i]<0:
     ...:         x[i] = 0
     ...: 
In [103]: x
Out[103]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

But usually in `numpy` we don't need to iterate (or rather prefer not to).  Instead we can test all the values at once.  Sticking with the 1d array for simplicity:

```
In [104]: x = np.arange(-3,4)
In [105]: mask = x<0
In [106]: mask
Out[106]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False])
In [107]: x[mask]
Out[107]: array([-3, -2, -1])
In [108]: x[mask] = 0
In [109]: x
Out[109]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```